# Auto Scaling of kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Scnerio :

```
I have two Kafka topics : 

  topic1: 1 partition
  topic2: 20 partitions

  topic1 receives 50 messages every hour(processing time of a message 5 sec)
  topic2 receives 1000 - 5000 messages distributed uniformly throughout the day.(processing time of a message 10 sec)
```

To consumes message to Kafka topics I have two consumer groups consumergroup1,consumergroup2.

```
 consumergroup1 has 1 consumer and consumes from topic1.
 consumergroup2 has 5 consumers and consumes from topic2.
```

Queries:

- Since topic1 receives 50 messages per hour and in order to consume it, I need to have 1 consumer always active. Is there a mechanism through which I can start or stop consumer automatically based on the lag in the topic?
- topic2 receives messages between 1000 - 5000 is there a the number of consumers can be scaled-up(to the max number of partitions) and scaled-down (to 1) automatically based on the lag in the topic?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Kafka does not provide any way for starting and stopping consumers dynamically out of the box.

---

However, I would say that it is definitely possible to achieve this by writing your own pipeline. It depends on what technologies you are currently using (and/or willing to use in the future) and how you are currently monitoring lag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Giorgos Myrianthous. Is there any open-source framework that I can use to build the pipeline?